# Broken view clipping/padding on API 21+

Tags: android, material-design, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat, androidx

android API 19:

[image]

[image]

android API 21:   (without any margin)

[image]

[image]

same results on emulator and real device, in appcompat and androidx.

How can i get picture like on KitKat, but on Lollipop devices? Because some CardView's on Lollipop devices looks like one big broken view

music recycler item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/musicrecyclerhelpLinearLayout1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/musicrecyclerhelpTextView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="why you can see this?"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/v_play"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:id="@+id/musicrecyclerhelpFloatingActionButton1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

card views code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: Please formulate a question, explain what you'd like to achieve and what you've tried so far (layout code).

Comment: @MarkusPenguin enough code?